# Is it a good idea to date as _id when storing time-series data?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB. I'm writing a python script to scrape and update stock quotes data. The script will run once to scrape and build a database up to the latest and then run everyday for updating.

After some researching, I think MongoDb fits the bill. Currently, I'm setting up the date as '_id' because I want to ensure uniqueness (since the update also scrapes from a page containing data from previous days).

Is it a potential disastrous idea? If so, how should I do otherwise? Thanks

Comment: it's not clear what the requirements are and what you want to do. is it a good idea? who knows...

Comment: Say, today I run my script and I get a collection of APPL EOD until 3/25/2014. Tomorrow I run my script again. It will scrape a page that not only includes 3/26/2014 EOD but also EOD of previous five days. If I use date as '_id' to ensure uniqueness, is it a good idea?

Comment: do you only follow one stock? if not, how is _id going to be unique?

Comment: I have a collection for each symbol.

Comment: again, not sure what's you're doing (how do you want to query the data later), but that's probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

No, It's not a good idea, because, by default, MongoDB already saves the timestamp in the _id:

You can retrieve the _id data using this code:

```
date = new Date( parseInt( _id.toString().substring(0,8), 16 ) * 1000 )
```

I'd use the auto-generated MongoDB _id

**EDIT: (Brought from comments)** If you are using PyMongo, the objectid python object has the attribute `generation_time`from which you can extract the related `datetime.datetime` instance . [PyMongo API Doc](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html)

```
>>> ObjectId().generation_time
```

Comment: it is always fair game to parse the string if you assume you dont have the python-bson library.  But if you do, you can simply read the attribute ObjectId().generation_time.  http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html#pymongo.objectid.ObjectId.generation_time